# How can I do filtering between two matrix?

Tags: text-processing

File1:

```
91  23  56  44  87  77
99  34  56  22  22  95
41  88  26  79  60  27
95  55  66  69  92  25
```

File2:

```
pass fail pass pass pass fail
pass fail pass fail fail pass
pass pass fail pass pass fail
pass pass fail pass pass fail
```

As I want to sum up the total fail marks for each row, here is the expected output.

output:

```
100
78
53
91
```

I would like to ask that how can I do the filtering on file1 based on the word "fail" in file2 in order to get the sum of fail marks.

Comment: What is producing these two files and can't that program do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need an `END` section:

```
awk '
NR == FNR       {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) F[i,NR] = $i
                 next
                }
                {T = 0
                 for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) T += ($i=="fail")?F[i,FNR]:0
                 print T
                }
' file[12]
100
78
53
91
```

Comment: You are right, END section is redundant, +1.

Answer (score 10):

I would use a matrix language for such a task, e.g. GNU Octave.

Assuming you converted the pass/fail file into numerical values, e.g.:

```
sed 's/pass/1/g; s/fail/0/g' passfail > passfail.nums
```

You can now do the following:

```octave
marks    = dlmread('marks');
passfail = dlmread('passfail.nums');

for i = 1:size(marks)(1)
  sum(marks(i,:)(passfail(i,:) == 0))
end
```

Output:

```
ans =  100
ans =  78
ans =  53
ans =  91
```

Answer (score 7):

While I think using `awk` is good for portability, other languages seem easier to write and read for this task. GNU Octave was mentioned but does not come pre-installed on most machines. On the other hand, most systems have a version of python preinstalled. Here is a python version:

```py
for marks, decisions in zip(open('file1').readlines(), open('file2').readlines()):
    row_score = 0
    for mark, decision in zip(marks.split(), decisions.split()):
        if decision == 'fail':
            row_score += int(mark)
    print(row_score)
```

which returns the outputs you expected.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my `awk` approach:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[NR"-"i]=$i; next} \
            {for(j=1;j<=NF;j++) if($j=="fail") b[FNR]+=a[FNR"-"j]} \
         END{for(k in b) print b[k]}' file1 file2
```

Awk doesn't support two-dimensional arrays, so we cooked ones by combining two numbers (row and field) in the same array index. The output is:

```
100
78
53
91
```

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '
  BEGIN{ pf=ARGV[2]; ARGV[2]="" }
  { getline l <pf; split(l, a); n=0;
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(a[i]=="fail") n+=$i;
    print n }
' file1 file2
100
78
53
91
```

Just like @Maxim's python version, but unlike all the other answers, this is processing the two files in parallel, line by line, instead of loading one of them whole into memory.

Answer (score 2):

I guess using an `Awk` script would make this requirement a bit easy to solve. Do something like below. I guess its a bit slower than now posted jimmij's answer

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f


FNR == NR {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if ( $i == "fail")
            idxArray[FNR] = (idxArray[FNR]) ? (idxArray[FNR]" "i):(i)
        next
}{
    delete Array
    delete Line
    i=""
    j=""
    sum=""
    n=split(idxArray[FNR],Array," ")
    l=split($0,Line," ")
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for (j=1;j<=l;j++)
            if (Array[i] == j )
                sum += Line[j]
    print sum
}
```

and run the script as

```
awk -f script.awk file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
paste file[12] | awk '{T=0; for (i=1; i<=NF/2; i++) T += ($(i+NF/2)=="fail")?$i:0; print T}'
100
78
53
91
```