# Replace same line in file 1 from file 2 with conditon

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression

**File 1:**

```
19a9s
c9019
5777
```

**File 2:**

```
99a9s
89019
10919
```

**Expected output**

```
19a9s
89019
5777
```

So in `file 1` on `line#2` it's start with letter `c`. which i would like to use it as condition if the line start with letter `c` so i want to replace it from the second file which is `file 2`

I Tried with the following but failed to give me the expected output:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR{         #for lines in first file
        S[NR] = $0     #put line in array `S` with row number as index 
        next           #starts script from the beginning
    }
    /^c/{$0=S[FNR]}{             #for line stared with `c`
        $0=S[++count]  #replace line by corresponded array element
    }
    1                  #alias for `print $0`
    ' file2 file1
```

Comment: @don_crissti i don't know from where to start :(. sorry

Comment: @don_crissti sorry for touting my own garbage, but I don't think it's advisable and/or necessary to save an entire file in an array. `awk` is perfectly able to process two files in parallel, [line by line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/480622/308316)

Comment: @mosvy - no problem, while you're right I think the array method is easier to digest for someone not knowing awk but wanting to start learning.

Comment: @don_crissti i edited the code but the same :S

Comment: @don_crissti same !

Comment: no problem; now, if you take the time to understand the code and return here later and explain how it  works I'll upvote your answer. You can then try doing it the way _mosvy_ suggested (with `getline`, which is the optimal way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
    NR == FNR{         #for lines in first file
        S[NR] = $0     #put line in array `S` with row number as index 
        next           #starts script from the beginning
    }
    /^c/{$0=S[FNR]}{             #for line stared with `c`
    }
    1                  #alias for `print $0`
    ' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

How far would

```
paste file[12] | sed 's/^c[^   ]*      //; t; s/       .*$//;'
19a9s
89019
5777
```

get you?